# Hexagone rotation html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm looking to make a class to draw hexagone and rotate it, but I don't find the way to define the rotation point on the center.
Thank you.

```
function Hexagone (sides, size, centerX, centerY, rotation) {
  this.sides = sides
  this.size = size
  this.centerX = centerX
  this.centerY = centerY
  this.rotation = rotation || 0
}

Hexagone.prototype.draw = function() {
  ctx.beginPath()
  // Reset transformation matrix
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.translate(this.centerX, this.centerY)
  ctx.rotate(this.rotation * Math.PI / 180)
  ctx.moveTo(this.centerX + this.size * Math.cos(0), this.centerY +    this.size * Math.sin(0))
  for (var i = 0; i <= this.sides; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(this.centerX + this.size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / this.sides), this.centerY + this.size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / this.sides))
  }

  //temp style
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000"
  ctx.lineWidth = 2
  ctx.stroke()
}
```

Comment: Quite correct...glad you worked it out! You should post your answer (and later accept it) so that your question comes off the "unanswered" list. ;-)

Comment: The linked pen appear to be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found:

```
// Reset transformation matrix
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
// We need to translate before
ctx.translate(this.centerX, this.centerY)
ctx.rotate(this.rotation * Math.PI / 180)
// And after
ctx.translate(-this.centerX, -this.centerY)
// Don't forget to reset the matrix on the beginning.
```

You can check the full code on codepen.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdgJWo